# Error al descargar de FirebaseStorage. Error desconocido

Tags: android-studio, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy intentando descargar un fichero Akp desde Firebase Storage para posteriormente instalarlo.
Estas son las reglas que estoy aplicando. Tambien he intentado con "if true" por si fuera el problema pero en las notificaciones de storage me dan las peticiones como aceptadas, pero sigo sin poder descargar el fichero.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read : if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

El fragmento de codigo es el siguiente. (es posible que alguna parte de instalar
este mal ya que nunca lo he usado pero aun no he podido probarlo.

```
public void downloadUpdate() {
    StorageReference gsReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("LeaderBoard-Upd.apk");
    final String rutadestino = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
    final String nombrearchivo = "LeaderBoard-Upd.apk";
    final Uri archivodestino = Uri.parse("file://" + rutadestino+nombrearchivo);
    File localFile = new File(rutadestino+nombrearchivo);
    if (localFile.exists()) {
        localFile.delete();
    }

    gsReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
             //Local temp file has been created
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(rutadestino+nombrearchivo));
                Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                install.setData(contentUri);
                startActivity(install);
                //unregisterReceiver(this);
                finish();
            } else {
                Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                install.setDataAndType(archivodestino,
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                startActivity(install);
                //unregisterReceiver(this);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
            int errorCode = ((StorageException) exception).getErrorCode();
            String errorMessage = exception.getMessage();
            Emergente.ErrorCode(1,getApplicationContext());
        }
    });
}
```

al final entra en el OnFailure y me arroja lo siguiente:
errorcode "13000"
errorMessage "An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response."
cause "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

He probado otras cosas por si la referencia al fichero estuviese mal pero en esos casos me da un error de mala referencia al archivo.
Estoy logueado en Firebase Auth ya que estoy utilizando FireStore y la URL de hecho la saco de ahi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solucionado. el problema es que la aplicacion intentaba crear un fichero donde poder descargar en una ruta en la cual no tiene permisos por defecto
la solucion es crear el fichero dentro de la carpeta de la propia app para la cual no te piden permisos (API <= 18 si que requiere permisos para ello)

```
File localFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), ".apk");
```